# Dynamic stored procedure by concatenating the parameters

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, concatenation

I am trying to write a stored procedure which works dynamically by concatenating the parameters which are passed.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE E_Enquiry 
    (IN SourceQueue1 VARCHAR(30),
     IN PayloadMsgId1 VARCHAR(100),
     IN EventSource1 VARCHAR(100) 
     ) 
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
LANGUAGE SQL
RETURNRT: BEGIN
    DECLARE query_String VARCHAR(32000);
    SET query_String = 'SELECT PayloadMsgId,ExceptionId,EventSource,E_Message.InterfaceId,CreationTime,SourceProtocol,ErrorMessage,Severity,InterfaceName 
        from E_Message,E_Config where' ;
    if SourceQueue1 <> NULL THEN
                SET query_String = query_String + 'SourceQueue='+SourceQueue1+'and';        
    end if;
    if PayloadMsgId1 <> NULL THEN
                SET query_String = query_String + 'PayloadMsgId='+PayloadMsgId1+'and';      
    end if;
    if EventSource1 <> NULL THEN
                SET query_String = query_String + 'EventSource='+EventSource1;      
    end if;
RETURNCR: BEGIN
    DECLARE C1 CURSOR WITH RETURN TO CALLER FOR
    query_String;    
open C1;    
END RETURNCR;    
END RETURNRT
```

I am not sure whether the query_String holds the query when called in cursor. This stored procedure is not returning any values. Could someone help to overcome this?

Comment: 1) You're open to SQL Injection - the statement you create should still be parameterized to avoid this.  2)  Are you sure that there's data for the given query to find?  Run the statement alone, or install a monitor that watches for it.  3) How do you attempt to read from the procedure in the caller?  4) You probably don't need the multiple `BEGIN` statements (just one), and you don't need to label them.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse, Yes I am sure that the query which I use has data. I have run it separately and checked. I am using mule database connector to call this stored procedure. The only problem is that, the appended query is not getting substituted in the cursor.